# Get RGB image pixel values as 16bit and fill lists

Tags: python, image, pixel, 16-bit

With ImageMagick I can convert any image into a textfile with pixel/value representation of every single (RGB) pixel. This is a sample output of an 16bit integer png file obtained via "convert spektrum.png spektrum.txt"

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1553,24,65535,srgba
0,0: (16192,7721,24114,65535)  #3F401E295E32FFFF  srgba(25%,12%,37%,1)
```

this represents the the first upper left pixel (0,0) in the image with its rgb(a) values.

**Question:**
How can I read the same image with Python(3) into a list/array with its 16bit values? If I use pillow to read this PNG file

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("spektrum.png")
pix = im.load()
print(pix[2,5])
(67, 35, 99, 255)
```

I only get 0-255 RGBA-values from it.

Comment: There’s probably a simpler way, but try this `convert spektrum.png -compress none pnm:-`

Comment: @MarkSetchell nice idea, but that spits out rgb values in a pattern that I dont understand, I dont see a way to parse that output. It should be "Plain PPM(PNM)" as described here: http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html but the output does not follow it. It looks like the output is simply R-G-B value pixel after pixel but then somewhere are linebreaks that I dont understand.

Comment: It looks like Pillow does not support 16bit.. "Sorry, it's a limitation of Pillow. We don't have the ability to read multichannel images that are more than 8 bit per channel." https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1828#issuecomment-209020147

Comment: I found python/opencv can read 16bit, I will try that

Answer (score 1):

I can read now 16 bit values with opencv:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> img = cv2.imread('spektrum.png',-1) # -1 read format as is
>>> print(img.dtype)
uint16
>>> px = img[0,0]
>>> print(px)
[24114  7721 16192 65535]
```